# OpenVZ 7 memory leak

Tags: kernel, openvz, memory-leak

Looking for some assistance on a memory leak issue wherein the RAM consumption keeps gradually increasing day by day and within a span of 6 to 7 days, it reaches 100%. (I have to reboot then). [Ram consumption graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BWMy.png)

The RAM drop is due to reboot. Each reboot is in 5-7 days to time frame.
The containers hosted on the node shouldn't be of concern since I migrated them from old server where everything was stable.

OS:                Virtuozzo 7.0.16

Kernel: 3.10.0-1127.18.2.vz7.163.46 GNU/Linux

I changed the kernel to an older version in order to check if in case the kernal was an issue but it was of no help.

This is a 128 GB RAM server with 32GB swap (which I now increased to 64GB with swapinesss also set to 30, but again of no help)

For managing the containers, I am making use of virtualizor.

CPU, load, I/O everything is stable.

Answer (score 0):

Found it's a bug in OpenVZ 7.0.16 https://bugs.openvz.org/browse/OVZ-7278

Edit /etc/vz/ploop.conf change to

```
USE_KAIO_FOR_EXT4=no
```

Comment: Yes, it was posted from our team member :)  It was a long chase and finally we were able to get BUG recognized and resolved. Your answer will help any new person who is looking for the answer.